# ROS Answers SE migration: AttributeError

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi i am trying to use the split command so that i can split the voice input but getting an error
" AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' "

code snippet is

```
def talkback(self, msg):

command = self.get_command(msg.data)

# Print the recognized words on the screen
rospy.loginfo("Command: " + msg.data)
#rospy.loginfo(msg.data)

#some_str = command
#some_wrd = 'time'

if 'time' in command.split():
    msg.data = strftime("%H:%M:%S ")
    self.soundhandle.say(msg.data, self.voice)
elif 'name' in command.split():
    self.soundhandle.say("my name is atom", self.voice) 
else:
        return
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48993/attributeerror/) by [karan4515](https://answers.ros.org/users/3123/karan4515/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2012-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The variable `command` is probably empty, i.e. set to None.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karan4515](https://answers.ros.org/users/3123/karan4515/) on 2012-11-23**:
hey thanks for the help. i have changed the code a bit and now it work fine for time but for name it don't any help